# How do I smooth out hair particles?

Tags: rendering

[image]

See how the strands are linear and not curvy. How do make it so the strands are curvy and look more natural

Comment: Please show you setting for the particles/hair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try to change the Steps.

Inside the particle system go to Display (2.79) or Viewport Display (2.8) >>

[image]

[image]

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you. The hair looks more slick and smooth. Another thing I want to appreciate is the fact that you recorded an example of both popular versions (I personally use 2.79)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Change the hair segments setting to a higher value.

My suggestion is ..... 16